# При выборе select добавить класс для div

Tags: html, jquery

Есть необходимость при выборе `option` с определённым значением в `select`, задать класс `active` определённому `div`. На данный момент есть код; класс добавляется, но не убирается у остальных `div`.

```js
$("#category").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".11, .22, .33, .44, .55, .66, .77, .88, .99, .100, .110, .120, .130")
        .not($(this.value).addClass('active'))
});
```

```css
.markers_wrap a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="catlist[]" id="category">
    <option>Выбрать блок</option>
    <option value=".11">блок 1</option>
    <option value=".22">блок 2</option>
    <option value=".33">блок 3</option>
    <option value=".44">блок 4</option>
    <option value=".55">блок 5</option>
    <option value=".66">блок 6</option>
    <option value=".77">блок 7</option>
    <option value=".88">блок 8</option>
    <option value=".99">блок 9</option>
    <option value=".100">блок 10</option>
    <option value=".110">блок 11</option>
    <option value=".120">блок 12</option>
    <option value=".130">блок 13</option>
</select>

<div class="11">блок 1</div>
<div class="22">блок 2</div>
<div class="33">блок 3</div>
<div class="44">блок 4</div>
<div class="55">блок 5</div>
<div class="66">блок 6</div>
<div class="77">блок 7</div>
<div class="88">блок 8</div>
<div class="99">блок 9</div>
<div class="100">блок 10</div>
<div class="1110">блок 11</div>
<div class="120">блок 12</div>
<div class="130">блок 13</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#category").change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $(this.value).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.markers_wrap a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="catlist[]" id="category">
    <option>Выбрать блок</option>
    <option value=".11">блок 1</option>
    <option value=".22">блок 2</option>
    <option value=".33">блок 3</option>
    <option value=".44">блок 4</option>
    <option value=".55">блок 5</option>
    <option value=".66">блок 6</option>
    <option value=".77">блок 7</option>
    <option value=".88">блок 8</option>
    <option value=".99">блок 9</option>
    <option value=".100">блок 10</option>
    <option value=".110">блок 11</option>
    <option value=".120">блок 12</option>
    <option value=".130">блок 13</option>
</select>
<div class="11">блок 1</div>
<div class="22">блок 2</div>
<div class="33">блок 3</div>
<div class="44">блок 4</div>
<div class="55">блок 5</div>
<div class="66">блок 6</div>
<div class="77">блок 7</div>
<div class="88">блок 8</div>
<div class="99">блок 9</div>
<div class="100">блок 10</div>
<div class="110">блок 11</div>
<div class="120">блок 12</div>
<div class="130">блок 13</div>
```

Comment: $('div').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('active');}); - очень элегантно!

Comment: @VladVlad, спасибо, братиш

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ребятки ! Оказывается всё просто)

Comment: @Doofy [обращайся](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC)

Comment: @VladVlad, [неприменно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC). Ну а чё не так? Если автору будет надо, запилит в общий блок дивы и перебирать их будет

Comment: @Doofy хуже чем копипаст чужого кода, может быть только копипаст чужого кривого кода - зачем плохому учить

Comment: @VladVlad, у кого я скопипастил по твоему?

Comment: @Doofy я об авторе вопроса, вот он сейчас копирнул твой код, запомнил, и будет тулить это везде - ну ладно, на этом закончим

Comment: Еще один вопрос. Точка в значении value обязательна ? А то я наваял  по быстрому)

Comment: @RazorXL, обязательна, в селекторе точка обозначает класс. Без неё будет тэг

Comment: @VladVlad, код я почти сразу поправил, не пользуюсь jquery. А на js такая тема не прокатитила бы. Ты остынь, все мы люди ошибаемся

Comment: @Doofy та норм все :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем всем div-ам общий класс (допустим "test"), а перед добавлением класса указывающего на активность делаем так `$('.test').removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы завернул все дивы в общий родительский и сделал так (оставить нужно конечно же один из двух вариантов):

```js
$("#category").change(function() {
// вариант №1 
     $(".categories div" + $(this).val()).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
// вариант №2
     $(".categories div.active").removeClass('active');
     $($(this).val()).addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.markers_wrap a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories">
    <select name="catlist[]" id="category">
        <option>Выбрать блок</option>
        <option value=".11">блок 1</option>
        <option value=".22">блок 2</option>
        <option value=".33">блок 3</option>
        <option value=".44">блок 4</option>
        <option value=".55">блок 5</option>
        <option value=".66">блок 6</option>
        <option value=".77">блок 7</option>
        <option value=".88">блок 8</option>
        <option value=".99">блок 9</option>
        <option value=".100">блок 10</option>
        <option value=".110">блок 11</option>
        <option value=".120">блок 12</option>
        <option value=".130">блок 13</option>
    </select>
    <div class="11">блок 1</div>
    <div class="22">блок 2</div>
    <div class="33">блок 3</div>
    <div class="44">блок 4</div>
    <div class="55">блок 5</div>
    <div class="66">блок 6</div>
    <div class="77">блок 7</div>
    <div class="88">блок 8</div>
    <div class="99">блок 9</div>
    <div class="100">блок 10</div>
    <div class="1110">блок 11</div>
    <div class="120">блок 12</div>
    <div class="130">блок 13</div>
</div>
```